# Rsyslog: how to separate incoming logs with IP addresses

Tags: syslog

I am trying to setup an Rsyslog with the following configuration:
I listen to the 514 port to receive data from different hosts: 172.16.111.222, 172.16.111.111 and 172.16.222.111. And I want to store thoses logs in different folder for each host.
So I did this conf:

```
$ModLoad imudp


$Ruleset RemoteConnections
$RulesetCreateMainQueue on
$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionQueueFileName dbremotecons
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
*.* ~


$InputUDPServerBindRuleset RemoteConnections
$UDPServerRun 514

if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.111.222' then /var/log/prod1/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log
& ~
if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.111.111' then /var/log/prod1/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log
& ~

if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.222.111' then /var/log/product2/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log
& ~
```

Unfortunately, it is not working, rsyslog is not logging anything.
I am not sure what "& ~" means, I found that on internet.

Any ideas to make it work ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use placeholders directly in the rules. Use templates instead. The following should work:

```
$template DynaFile,"/var/log/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
*.* -?DynaFile
```

Or, to be closer to your code:

```
$template prod1,"/var/log/prod1/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
$template prod2,"/var/log/prod2/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.111.111' then ?prod1
if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.111.222' then ?prod1
if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.222.111' then ?prod2
```

Answer (score 2):

"~" means discard or stop, which is a rsyslog "[action](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html?highlight=discard)".

So:

```
if $fromhost-ip=='172.16.111.222' then /var/log/prod1/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log
& ~
```

means that if the "if ... then ..." statement works, i.e. the condition is met and message is logged into a file, then stop - do not proceed any further.